# how can I access my public method from aspx code behind to a public class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a public method in my aspx code behind called PhotoDatabinding, what it does is to bind the database to List view control.

```
public void PhotoDatabinding()
{


lnqPhotoDataContext dbCon = new lnqPhotoDataContext();
var res = from p in dbCon.Photos orderby p.PhotoID descending select new {          p.PhotoID, p.FileName };

    lvSubAlbumDB.DataSource = res;
    lvSubAlbumDB.DataBind();

 }
```

Now, inside my public class called Process I have a a method called UpdateSave. my question is how can I access the PhotoBinding method so that it will look like this

```
public class Process
{
public UpdateSave()
{
    ....some code
    PhotoDatabinding();

}

}
```

Thanks and appreciate all your help and suggestions.

Comment: What is the relationship between `Process` and the class that `PhotoDatabinding` is in?  Does that class create an instance of `Process`, or create a class that creates it?

Comment: Typically, your page would utilize the Process class, not the other way around. You're making calls in the wrong direction between layers.

Comment: I agree with David this is wrong direction call.

Comment: David is correct. I would rethink your design. It'll make your life easier.

Comment: Silverlight FileUpload control has a class called FileUploadProcess that upload photos into your server. My PhotoBinding method inside my aspx.cs is basically to update the listview to update the page with the current upload photo. Thanks guys for your comment and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

To clear the flow:

You need to create a class which is going to be used only to get the data from database or to update data

```
public class PhotoAccess
{

  public class PhotoInfo
  {
    public int PhotoID {get; set;}
    public string FileName {get; set;}
  }

  public IEnumerable<PhotoInfo> GetPhotos()
  {
   using ( var dbCon = new lnqPhotoDataContext())
   {
      var res = from p in dbCon.Photos 
            orderby p.PhotoID descending 
            select new PhotoInfo 
                       {
                          p.PhotoID, 
                          p.FileName 
                       };
      return res.AsEnumerable();
    }
  }
  public bool UpdateSave(...)
  {
      ... code to do update or save, use here only classes for working with the DB
  }
}
```

Then in the code behind of the page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
       var dataAccess = new PhotoAccess();
       var items = dataAccess.GetPhotos();

       lvSubAlbumDB.DataSource = items;
       lvSubAlbumDB.DataBind();
   }
}
protected void btSave_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dataAccess = new PhotoAccess();
    dataAccess.UpdateSave(...pass here the parameters or an object which is going to be inserted);

    var items = dataAccess.GetPhotos();

    lvSubAlbumDB.DataSource = items;
    lvSubAlbumDB.DataBind();
}
```

You might also refactor the binding code into another method of the Page class

```
private void BindAlbum()
{
   var dataAccess = new PhotoAccess();
   var items = dataAccess.GetPhotos();    

   lvSubAlbumDB.DataSource = items;
   lvSubAlbumDB.DataBind();
}
```

And Page Load would be:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (!Page.IsPostBack)
       {
           BindAlbum();
       }
    }
```

and the Update handler

```
 protected void btSave_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dataAccess = new PhotoAccess();
        dataAccess.UpdateSave(...pass here the parameters or an object which is going to be inserted);

        BindAlbum();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Adrian, first of all I appreciate all the example you provide. to give you more idea of what I'm trying to achieve is that on my Add Photo page I have listview control with databinding and a silverlight [link](FileUpload) control which I cannot call the  PhotoDatabinding method to update the Listview control that is in my Add Photo page.

Comment: There must be an way so that control raises an event which says the image was uploaded.

Comment: Exactly... but I couldn't raise any event in silverlight FileUpload.xap control upload button.